# Two threads doesn't use the same function correctly in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem with the threads, here is a code:

```
class myThread
{
    public int _start, _finish;
    string[] new_array = new string[10];
    public static string[] existed_array = new string[20];    
    public myThread(string name, int start, int finish)
    {
        _start = start;
        _finish = finish;
        Thread thread = new Thread(this.Get);
        thread.Name = name;
        thread.Start();//передача параметра в поток
     }

    void Get()
    {
        for (int ii = _start; ii < _finish; ii++)
        {
           // i put data in existed array in Main()
           // new array is just an array where i want to put existed data
           new_array[ii] = existed_array[ii];
           // but in output new_array[0]=null; new_array[1]=value
        }
    }
}

void Main ()
{
    // For example
    myThread.existed_array = {1, 2 , 3, ...}

    myThread t1 = new myThread("Thread 1", 0, 1);
    myThread t2 = new myThread("Thread 2", 1, 2);
}
```

Threads run Get() with different parametrs, but in output there is just the parametrs of the second thread.
as i can see from step-by-step program runs every line in Get function 2 times, so this is the point, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: you'll have to show us some of the code from Get()

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You'll have to provide more information and describe your issue more clearly.

Comment: and a better question title wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - your question isn't answerable at the moment, really...

Comment: `myThread t2 = new myThread("Thread 1", 0, 1);` is that a typo on the question or is that how you have it in your code? Also, where are new_array and existed_array defined?

Comment: sorry, edited.. yes, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, your code runs as it's supposed to.

In your comments, you claim that "but in output new_array[0]=null; new_array[0]=value". My interpretation of this is that in your second thread, `new_array[0] = null`, and in your first thread, `new_array[0] = <some value>`.

As per your code, `new_array` is a non-static variable, which means its not shared across threads.

Considering the parameters you've provided to your second thread, it never touches the 0th in the array. You've set the start value to 1, so `ii` starts at 1. That means you never set `new_array[0]` to anything, and thus it defaults to `null`.

Comment: **new_array[0] = null, new_array[1] = value**

Comment: first thread ("Thread 1", 0, 1) takes 0th element from the existed_array and put it in new_array[0], second thread ("Thread 2", 1, 2) takes 1st element from the existed_array and put it in new_array[1], so it should be two elements in the new_array, but there just one - new_array[1]

Comment: But new_array is **not** a static variable. You have __2__ instances of it, one for each `myThread` object. So each instance of `new_array` will only have one element.